# How can I stop keyboard opening?

Tags: android

In my app I want to fill my `EditText` by clicking Buttons; with my own keyboard. So I dont want that the keyboard opens if I click on the `EditText`. Is that possible?

Comment: Please use the correct class names when posting questions. `TextField` isn't a valid Android class (or at least not a native one) . Remember you question might be viewed by other people in the future - it is better to be as accurate as possible to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code..
`EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text)`;
`editText.setInputType(0);` 
OR
`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`
`imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: @MAYUR: You forgot to cast the return of `findViewById(...)` on your first example. It should be `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);`

Answer (score 5):

Either in manifest file..

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Or in your activity

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: thx, but the fastest way is the first one from the other answer